# What is reversible change for ideal gas?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws, terminology

What are the reversible and irreversible changes for an ideal gas? Is it the change that keeps the ideal gas law during the change? Is any reversible change a sum of changes satisfying the ideal gas law $(pV = nRT)?$ If so, it looks to me like any change is reversible if it is done very slowly.

Comment: The concept of ideal gas has no bearing on this whatsoever. You are right, though, in that the changes which are done very slowly tend to be reversible.

Comment: See [Reversible_process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_%28thermodynamics%29)

Comment: thank you. Because the word "reversible" always comes with another word "isothermal" in my textbook, I was initially under impression that all the reversible changes were isothermal ones.